# How to use form_with with self join in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` model which can have many child accounts. I have set up the model as below

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :child_accounts, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "parent_account_id"
  belongs_to :parent_account, class_name: "User", optional: true
end
```

I have created a `ChildAccountsController` to handle the child accounts creation etc. and defined routes as below.

```rb
resources :users do
  resource :child_accounts
end
```

But I can get `form_with` to work in this situation. as

```rb
form_with(model: [current_user, @child_account], local: true) do
#...
end
```

form_with infers the url from the model class since both of them are User. the path it infers `user_user_path` instead of `user_child_accounts_path`.

So, is there a rails way to create forms with self joins? Or do I have manually handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you have a pluralization error:

```
resources :users do
  resources :child_accounts 
end
```

`resource` is used to declare [singular resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

But the [polymorphic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) will not be able route to that path automatically anyways, when you pass model instances to `form_for`, `form_with`, `link_to` and `button_to` they deduce the name of route helper method by calling `#model_name` and using the methods of [`ActiveModel::Naming`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html). Since `@child_account` is an instance of User you get `user_users_path`. The polymorphic routing helpers are not aware of your associations.

It does not matter at all here if you use `form_for` or `form_with` as both use the exact same methods to figure out a path from a model or array of models.

You either need to explicitly pass the url:

```
form_with(model: @child_account, url: user_child_accounts_path(current_user), local: true) do
#...
end
```

Or use [single table inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html):

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string :type
    end
  end
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :child_accounts, 
    foreign_key: "parent_account_id",
    inverse_of: :parent_account
end

class ChildAccount < User
  belongs_to :parent_account, 
    class_name: "User",
    inverse_of: :child_accounts
end
```

```
class ChildAccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @child_account = current_user.child_accounts.new
  end

  def create
    @child_account = current_user.child_accounts.new(child_account_params)
    # ...
  end

  private
  def child_account_params
    params.require(:child_account)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```